# Behavior of JointTrajectoryActionController with a single goal

Tags: ros, pr2-controllers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I send the JointTrajectoryActionController a single goal using the SimpleActionClient with a velocity and acceleration of 0 each, will the commanded motor torques simply be like a PID controller with a fixed set point?

Will the r_arm_controller (which I am assuming is a JointTrajectoryActionController) start behaving like a JointPositionController in this case?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9428/behavior-of-jointtrajectoryactioncontroller-with-a-single-goal/) by [Advait Jain](https://answers.ros.org/users/219/advait-jain/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2011-03-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The desired position trajectory will be a fifth-order polynomial, with start and end boundary conditions of 0 velocities and accelerations. Also called a "minimum jerk" movement in some communities.

If you omit accelerations, you'll get a cubic spline. If you also omit velocities, you get linear interpolation. This is some documentation I found about this: http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_mechanism_controllers/JointSplineTrajectoryController

---

Originally posted by [kalakris](https://answers.ros.org/users/17/kalakris/) with karma: 529 on 2011-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Advait Jain](https://answers.ros.org/users/219/advait-jain/) on 2011-03-15**:
thanks a lot Mrinal, this was really useful!